# Need to find data from one dataframe and see if its another in Pandas [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I currently have 2 csv files and am reading them both in, and need to get the ID's in one csv and find them in the other so that I can get their row of data.  Currently I have the following code that I believe goes through the first dataframe but only is adding the last match onto the new dataframe.  I need it to add all of the subsequent rows however.
Here is my code:

```
patientSet = pd.read_csv("794_chips_RMA.csv")

affSet = probeset[probeset['Analysis']==1].reset_index(drop=True) 
houseGenes = probeset[probeset['Analysis']==0].reset_index(drop=True)

for x in affSet['Probeset']:
     #patients = patientSet[patientSet['ID']=='1557366_at'].reset_index(drop=True)
     #patients = patientSet[patientSet['ID']=='224851_at'].reset_index(drop=True)
     patients = patientSet[patientSet['ID']==x].reset_index(drop=True)

print(affSet['Probeset'])
print(patientSet['ID'])
print(patients)
```

The following is the output:

```
0      1557366_at
1       224851_at
2      1554784_at
3       231578_at
4    1566643_a_at
5       210747_at
6     231124_x_at
7     211737_x_at
Name: Probeset, dtype: object
0              1007_s_at
1                1053_at
2                 117_at
3                 121_at
4              1255_g_at
              ...       
54670     AFFX-ThrX-5_at
54671     AFFX-ThrX-M_at
54672    AFFX-TrpnX-3_at
54673    AFFX-TrpnX-5_at
54674    AFFX-TrpnX-M_at
Name: ID, Length: 54675, dtype: object
            ID  phchp003v1  phchp003v2  phchp003v3  ...  phchp367v1  phchp367v2  phchp368v1  phchp368v2
0  211737_x_at   12.223453   11.747159    9.941889  ...   14.828389    9.322779   10.609053   10.771162
```

as you can see, it is only matching the very last ID from the first dataframe, and not all of them.  How can I get them all to match and be in patients? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to use the merge function

```py
df_inner = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='inner')
```

check here https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/joining-dataframes-pandas search for "inner join"

--edit--
you can specify the columns (using left_on=None,right_on=None,) , look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging

Comment: So this will inner join the two dataframes on the 'id' column yes? However, one dataframe is named Probeset and the other is ID, so how would i go about this?

Comment: you can specify the columns (using left_on=None,right_on=None,) , look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging

Answer (score 0):

@Rui Lima already posted the correct answer, but you'll need to use the following to make it work:

```
df = pd.merge(patientSet , affSet, on='ID', how='inner')
```

Comment: So this will inner join the two dataframes on the 'id' column yes? However, one dataframe is named Probeset and the other is ID, so how would i go about this?

Comment: you can specify the columns (using left_on=None,right_on=None,) , look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging